# Rails Paperclip image to AXSLX file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, axlsx

I'm trying to save a Paperclip image to an AXSLX file.

This is the AXSLX code:

```
sheet.add_image(:image_src => imgurl, :noSelect => true, :noMove => true) do |image|
  image.width=720
  image.height=666
  image.start_at 0, 0
end
```

imgurl from the console =

```
>> imgurl
=> "http://localhost:3000/system/attachments/attaches/000/000/161/original/donut.jpeg?1401891882"
>>
```

The imgurl in a browser displays the image.

The error I get is:

```
Invalid Data: jpeg?1401891882. Pic.image_src must be one of ["gif", "jpeg", "png", "jpg"].
```

Thanks for the help!

UPDATE1

If I use imgurl = `http://localhost:3000/system/attachments/attaches/000/000/161/original/donut.jpeg`

I get `file does not exist`

Comment: looks like its complaining for `?1401891882` at the end. can you try after removing `?1401891882` at end, if it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you add

`require 'open-uri'`

In your code so that `File.open` can fetch a remote URL.

Thus:

- Use the `?`-less version of your URL (which you do in your update).
- Include `require "open-uri"`